# Merge two intersecting arrays into a HashMap, One Key & Multiples values

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a basic calendar to help automate Timesheets at work using Angular.js and Chrome Extensions, but for now I am stuck on this part.

Below you can see two arrays: `pastTwoWeeks` which is a list of dates from today back 14 days and Timesheet `entries` which were retrieved from an API - these will actually be objects with many properties but for now I am just using a simple date.

Here's a jsfiddle, am I on the right track? Thanks
http://jsfiddle.net/v599n/

```
var pastTwoWeeks = ['15/10/2013', '14/10/2013', '13/10/2013', 
    '12/10/2013', '11/10/2013', '10/10/2013', 
    '09/10/2013', '08/10/2013', '07/10/2013', 
    '06/10/2013', '05/10/2013', '04/10/2013', 
    '03/10/2013', '02/10/2013'];

var entries = ['11/10/2013', '11/10/2013', '11/10/2013', 
    '11/10/2013', '10/10/2013', '10/10/2013', '10/10/2013', 
    '09/10/2013', '09/10/2013', '09/10/2013', '08/10/2013', 
    '08/10/2013', '07/10/2013', '07/10/2013', '04/10/2013', 
    '04/10/2013', '03/10/2013', '03/10/2013', '02/10/2013', 
    '02/10/2013', '02/10/2013', '02/10/2013', '01/10/2013',
        '01/10/2013', '01/10/2013'];

var calander = {};

for(var j=0; j< pastTwoWeeks.length; j++) {   
    var key = pastTwoWeeks[j];
    if (key in calander == false) {
        calander[key] = {};
    }

    for(var i = 0; i< entries.length; i++) {
        var entry = entries[i];
        if(entry === key){
            calander[key][entry];
            console.log(key + " " + entry);
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve:

- 15/10/2013
- 14/10/2013
- 13/10/2013
- 12/10/2013
- 11/10/2013 (4 entries)

  - 11/10/2013
  - 11/10/2013
  - 11/10/2013
  - 11/10/2013

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Here's a jsfiddle, am I on the right track?

Not really.

> ```
> calander[key] = {};
> ```

I think you rather want an array of entries here, not an object.

> ```
> calander[key][entry];
> ```

This does not do anything. If you were trying to create a property, you would need to assign to it. Also, since all `entry`s are the same for a `key`, you would only overwrite the one and same property. Better `.push()` to an array.

> ```
> for(var j=0; j< pastTwoWeeks.length; j++) {   
>     for(var i = 0; i< entries.length; i++) {
>         if(entry === key)
> ```

That's rather inefficient. You can do better by executing the loops after each other, and just check whether your `entry` exists as a key of your `calender` which was previously filled with the `pastTwoWeeks`.

```
var calendar = {};
for (var i=0; i<pastTwoWeeks.length; i++) {
    var key = pastTwoWeeks[i];
    calendar[key] = [];
}
for (var i=0; i<entries.length; i++) {
    var entry = entries[i],
        key = entry; // this might change for more complex objects
    if (key in calendar) {
       calendar[key].push(entry);
       console.log(entry+" added to calendar at " + key);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was working on an answer with the same approach. I've taken @Bergi code and put it into a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Fresh/teRD8/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do what your looking for:

```
var pastTwoWeeks = ['15/10/2013', '14/10/2013', '13/10/2013', '03/10/2013', '02/10/2013'];
var entries = ['11/10/2013', '11/10/2013', '11/10/2013', '01/10/2013', '01/10/2013'];
var calander = {};

pastTwoWeeks.forEach(function(date) {
    calander[date] = [];
});

entries.forEach(function(date) {
    if (calander[date] === undefined) calander[date] = [];
    calander[date].push(date);
});
```

Comment: This was helpful too and is what I am ultimately trying to achieve but it doesn't answer the question at hand. Have an upvote though. Thanks :)